# data is not updated in Mysql php with PDO and mysqli code

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a page to display data, and an edit button(ajax) to edit the data. However, I used a PDO to display my data and I used mysqli to update my data. 
Will it be the reason why I am not able to update my data?

The problem that I am having now is:

data is not able to update in my data base and it is able to display.

My select and display code is below:

```
        <?php
    require_once 'db/dbfunction.php';
session_start();
        $user = $_SESSION['loginUser'];
        $accountId = $user["AccountID"];
        $stmt2 = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM applicantpersonaldetails apd "
                . "INNER JOIN existingbankproducts ext ON apd.ApplicantID = ext.ApplicantID "
                . "WHERE apd.AccountID =:accountId AND apd.applicantType ='main';");
        $stmt2->bindParam(':accountId', $accountId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        //if account id data type is varchar change the last parameter to `PDO::PARAM_str`
        $stmt2->execute();
        $totalBalance = 0;
        $totalMonthlyComm = 0;
        if ($stmt2->rowCount() > 0) {
            ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Financial Institution</th>
                    <th>Product Type</th>
                    <th>Balance</th>
                    <th>Monthly Commitment</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $totalBalance += $row['Balance'];
                    $totalMonthlyComm +=$row['MonthlyCommitment'];
                    $mainApplicantID = $row['ApplicantID'];
                    $_SESSION['mainApplicantID'] = $mainApplicantID;
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="finanIns1" id = "finanIns1" value="<?php echo $row['FinanicalInstituion']; ?>"></td>
                        <td><input list="proTypeList" name="proType1" id="proType1" value="<?php echo $row['ProductType']; ?>"></td>
                        <td id="balance"><input type="text" name="balance1" id="balance1" value="<?php echo $row['Balance']; ?>" ></td>
                        <td id="MonthyComm"><input type="text" name="monthlyComm1" id="monthlyComm1" value="<?php echo $row['MonthlyCommitment']; ?>" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </table>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

The code I use to update is below:

```
       <?php
session_start();
    require_once 'db/dbfunction.php';
        $con = open_connection();
        function updateBankProducts($con, $finanIns, $proType1, $balance1, $monthlyComm1, $mainApplicantId) {
            $sqlString = "UPDATE existingbankproducts SET FinanicalInstituion = '{$finanIns}' , ProductType = '{$proType1}' , Balance = '{$balance1}' , MonthlyCommitment = '{$monthlyComm1}' WHERE ApplicantID ='{$mainApplicantId}';";
            $insertResult = mysqli_query($con, $sqlString);

            if ($insertResult) {
                echo "Bank Products Updated !<br />";
            } else {
                echo " Error !";
                echo "{$sqlString}";
            }
        }

        if (isset($_POST['finanIns1'])) {
            $finanIns = $_POST['finanIns1'];
            $proType1 = $_POST['proType1'];
            $balance1 = $_POST['balance1'];
            $monthlyComm1 = $_POST['monthlyComm1'];
            $mainApplicantId = $_SESSION['mainApplicantId'];
            updateBankProducts($con, $finanIns, $proType1, $balance1, $monthlyComm1, $mainApplicantId);
        }
        ?>
```

The code for dbfunction.php is below:

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "fyp");
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DB_USER = 'root';
    $DB_PASS = '';
    $DB_NAME = 'fyp';
try{
        $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}",$DB_USER,$DB_PASS);
        $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

function open_connection() {

    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $connection;
    }
}

function close_connection($con) {
    if (isset($con)) {
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
}

try {
    $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}", $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using both `mysqli_` and `PDO`

Comment: Do you make 2 seperate connections, one for `mysqli_` and one for `PDO`?

Comment: I dont actually see any database connection code here, not even an include? Are you actually connecting to a database?

Comment: they are under the same connection, because I try changing PDO with mysqli but it is not working..

Comment: Change `WHERE ApplicantID ='{$mainApplicantId}';";` to `WHERE ApplicantID ='{$mainApplicantId}'";` Remove extra semi colon from this line. And, check.

Comment: You cannot connect using `PDO` and then use the `mysqli_` API

Comment: @NanaPartykar Will make no difference. The extra `;` is unnecessary but not illegal

Comment: **John** Stick to one database connection type and therefore one database API

Comment: I have upload the code code above.

Comment: Now I see you are using SESSION but do not have a `session_start()` in your script

Comment: Is it possible to change the PDO to mysqli?

Comment: Yes of course, Just change the code